# Endless For Loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, infinite-loop

This might be a silly question, but i can't actually understand why this FOR loop is running infinitely. The code is given below:

```
for(int k=0;k<size-1;k++){
    for(int i=k+1;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=k+1;j<size;j++){
            if(k=0){
                a[i][j]=((a[i][j]*a[k][k]) - (a[i][k]*a[k][j]));
            }else{
                a[i][j]=((a[i][j]*a[k][k]) - (a[i][k]*a[k][j]))/a[k-1][k-1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my case the value of size is 3, can anyone tell me why this is going to an infinite loop?

Comment: Because of `k=0` .

Comment: Turn on verbose warnings in your compiler, and I'll bet it would have told you where the problem was.

Comment: Thanks mate...rookie mistake

Answer (score 2):

`if(k=0){...` assigns the value 0 to k, so in the second iteration of the outer loop you "jump back" to the first iteration of the outer loop.

Use `if(k==0){...` instead.